# How does the IP address lease process work?

Tags: ip, dhcp

Curiosity. When a Computer-A has just received an IP lease, for example 2 hours. And immediately it is turned off for about 30 minutes. And then new devices are connected. Can any of these new devices receive the IP from Computer-A? Or even that (Computer-A) is off, the two-hour lease time is still valid

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: You should check out [wp:DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) and [RFC 1541](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1541).

Comment: Thanks. With (RFC 1541) solvers the question.